# Mod_Security false positive, how can I whitelist?

Tags: htaccess, apache

I am getting the following error while I am trying to create a web service. How can I white list this user agent?

I am not really able to understand the following error message.

> [error] [client 23.19.216.29] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match `(?i:(?:c(?:o(?:n(?:t(?:entsmartz|actbot/)|cealed defense|veracrawler)|mpatible(?: ;(?: msie|\\\\.)|-)|py(?:rightcheck|guard)|re-project/1.0)|h(?:ina(?: local browse 2\\\\.|claw)|e(?:rrypicker|esebot))|rescent internet toolpak)|w(?:e(?:b(?: (?:downloader|by ...` at REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent. [file `/usr/local/apache/conf/crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_35_bad_robots.conf`] [line `27`] [id `990012`] [rev `2`] [msg "Rogue web site crawler"] [data `User-Agent`] [severity `WARNING`] [ver `OWASP_CRS/2.2.7`] [maturity `9`] [accuracy `9`] [tag `OWASP_CRS/AUTOMATION/MALICIOUS`] [tag `WASCTC/WASC-21`] [tag `OWASP_TOP_10/A7`] [tag `PCI/6.5.10`] [hostname `www.xxxxx.co.in`] [uri `/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/13041237_1083988378328315_2154791894838540189_o.png`] [unique_id `WvkgH2cyon8ABTB9RFAAAAMW`]

Comment: Using shared hosting? if so, you will need to contact them.

Comment: @SimonHayter Yes shared hosting

Comment: What URL are requesting? Probably easier to change the URL in your "webservice"? Some _shared_ web hosts allow to you configure mod_security within your hosting control panel.

Comment: It looks like it is matching the `User-Agent` header and blacklisting based on that.   What browser or tool are you using for this request?